# Как список строк преобразовать по определенному признаку?

Tags: python, list

Дан список строк, в котором некоторые значения заканчиваются на '/'. Нужно такие значения и следующее за ними объединить в общую строку.
Пример:

```
['0.3/', '1.2/', '1.2/', '1.2', '11']
```

Результат:

```
['0.3/1.2/1.2/1.2', '11]
```

Строки с слешем могут быть как в начале, так в середине, так и в конце строки.
Последний символ строки не заканчивается слешем

Comment: В цикле обработки запоминайте предыдущее значение. И в зависимости от того, кончается ли предыдущее значение слешем либо добавляйте текущий элемент к предыдущему, либо добавляйте как новый в выходной список. Срезы вам очень помогут в этом всём. Но решить учебное задание вы должны в итоге сами.

Comment: `внешняя_переменная = ('/' in elem)` при переборе, зная, был ли слеш в предыдущем элементе, узнаете - нужно приклеить строку к `[-1]` элементу массива или `append`ить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну раз выкладывают уже код и я выложу. Без отдельного аккумулятора, достаточно текущего списка.

```
lst_in = ['0.3/', '1.2/', '1.2/', '1.2', '11']
lst_out = []
for x in lst_in:
    if lst_out and lst_out[-1].endswith('/'):
        lst_out[-1] += x
    else:
        lst_out.append(x)
print(lst_out)
```

Или вариант через `zip`:

```
lst_in = ['0.3/', '1.2/', '1.2/', '1.2', '11']
lst_out = []
for curr,prev in zip(lst_in, ['']+lst_in):
    if prev.endswith('/'):
        lst_out[-1] += curr
    else:
        lst_out.append(curr)
print(lst_out)
```

Answer (score 2):

Делаете переменную, в которую доклеиваете строки, если предыдущая строка заканчивалась на слэш. Если предыдущая строка не заканчивалась на слэш, добавляете все склеенные значения в выходной список, или выводите через yield в генераторе:

```
def join_slashes(s: list):
    accumulator = ''
    
    for item in s:
        if accumulator and not accumulator.endswith('/'):
            yield accumulator
            accumulator = ''
        
        accumulator += item
    
    yield accumulator


print(list(join_slashes(['0.3/', '1.2/', '1.2', '1.2/', '1.3', '11'])))
```

Через накопление в списке вместо генератора:

```
def join_slashes(s: list):
    result = []
    accumulator = ''
    
    for item in s:
        if accumulator and not accumulator.endswith('/'):
            result.append(accumulator)
            accumulator = ''
        
        accumulator += item
    
    result.append(accumulator)
    return result


print(join_slashes(['0.3/', '1.2/', '1.2', '1.2/', '1.3', '11']))
```

Вывод в обоих вариантах:

```
['0.3/1.2/1.2', '1.2/1.3', '11']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = ['0.3/', '1.2/', '1.2', '1.2/', '1.3', '11']
res = [x.lstrip(",") for x in "/,".join(lst).replace("//,",",").split("/")]
```

res:

```
['0.3,1.2,1.2', '1.2,1.3', '11']
```

Comment: `['0.3/1.2', '11']` => `['0.3', '1.2', '11']`

Comment: Данный код склеивает, но заменяет слэши на запятые, но судя по примеру результата в вопросе слэши так и должны оставаться слэшами

Comment: Вот такой вариант будет не будет заменять на запятые: `res = [x.rstrip("/") for x in "/,".join(lst).replace("//,", "/").split(",")]`  Но в любом случае это переусложнение, разве что для code golf подошло бы.